# Why is SQLite treating a number as a string?

Tags: sqlite

I have this DB whose types are not specified but the contents are all numeric. SQLite is treating them as string, I wanted it to treat them as numeric. Is it possible to do that without changing the SQLite definition? Also, I've seen other people complaining that SQLite was treating their strings as numeric... why does it do that for them, and why doesn't it do that for me? See below:

```
sqlite> .sche
CREATE TABLE cpu (timeid primary key, idle, myproc);
sqlite> select myproc, count(*) from cpu group by myproc;
myproc        count(*)
----------  ----------
0           1528
1           3
10          496
11          1293
12          688
13          2
15          1
2           42
3           71
4           54
5           38
6           108
7           186
8           384
9           315
sqlite> select max(myproc) from cpu;
max(myproc)
----------
9
sqlite> select sum(myproc), avg(myproc), count(*) from cpu;
sum(myproc)   avg(myproc)         count(*)
----------  ----------------  ----------
36043       6.91937032059896  5209
sqlite> select sum(myproc), avg(myproc), count(*) from cpu where fmon > 0;
sum(myproc)   avg(myproc)         count(*)
----------  ----------------  ----------
36043       6.91937032059896  5209
sqlite> select sum(myproc), avg(myproc), count(*) from cpu where fmon != 0;
sum(myproc)   avg(myproc)         count(*)
----------  ----------------  ----------
36043       6.91937032059896  5209
sqlite> select sum(myproc), avg(myproc), count(*) from cpu where fmon != "0";
sum(myproc)   avg(myproc)         count(*)
----------  ----------------  ----------
36043       9.79163270850312  3681
```

So, as you can see, `max()` is not returning the biggest numeral, but the biggest string instead. And when I try to filter out some lines using the `where` clause, it only works when I compare the column 'myproc' to the string "0", never to the numeral 0 (zero). And, as I said, "myproc" doesn't have any type defined. If I define it as `float` for example, it works.

Comment: If defining a type for your columns fixes the problem, why not do so? Most DB systems would require you to do so anyway.

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @IMSoP Call it scientific curiosity. :-) Or assume I am dealing with a DB that I'm not allowed to change. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of :-

> If no type is specified then the column has affinity NONE

and this :-

> A column with affinity NONE does not prefer one storage class over another and no attempt is made to coerce data from one storage class into another.

So you could try a cast expr :-

```
select max(cast(myproc AS INTEGER)) from cpu
```

**NOT TESTED**

Comment: Thanks, the cast worked. The explanation as to why, however, is still not very clear to me. My data is typed as "NONE", and it might not be coerced into being treated as INT... but I still don't know why it ends up being treated as STRING, and why other people's untyped strings are treated as INT. Is it just random? In any case, this solves my situation, so I'm accept it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I am not quite sure either especially for the "other" cases. It might help to study those in detail. Can you point me to those?

Comment: Hm, I've read of cases that the string was being treated as numeric and I could swear they didn't have a type, but maybe I was reading what I wanted. Here's one case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391461/how-can-i-prevent-sqlite-from-treating-a-string-as-a-number  He says his problem was declaring it as "STRING" instead of "TEXT".

Comment: @msb The values are strings because they were inserted into the database as strings.